# Using build variables in manifest shows cannot find symbol error in some places but not others

Tags: android, xml

This is more of an annoying one more than anything, as my project seems to build ok, but I'm trying to use the `${applicationId}` build variable in AndroidManifest.xml, and it works fine with no warning or errors in some places, like `android:label="${applicationId}"`, but it returns warnings/errors in the following :

```
  <activity 
         // various properties etc.>
        <intent-filter>

                <data android:scheme="${applicationId}.myContinuedString" />
        </intent-filter>
  </activity>
```

This shows as a red warning ("Cannot resolve symbol 'applicationId'"), but the app otherwise builds fine. But it won't go away. And I've tried the following:

- Invalidate cache/ restart
- Clean, rebuild
- Switching to different build variants
- Manually adding a manifestPlaceholder in build.gradle
- Moving `${applicationId}` to different locations in the manifest. As mentioned earlier, works in some places, like `android:label` but not in this `<data android:scheme` tag.

Any guidance as to why it's doing this?